# How to see which Java class is used at where

Tags: java

Hi my question is regarding to the internal Java libraries. As OpenJDK is available, are there any tools that could show me which class is used at what particular built-in libraries.
For instance I'd like to see where `Inet4Address` class is used within OpenJDK.

Comment: Since it is OpenJDK, try a Google search. One hit turned up: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/Inet4Address.java

Comment: @NedNowotny, that's the class itself. I don't need that, I need to know which classes use `Inet4Address` class.

Comment: Other Google search results will turn up other references, but even restricted to the OpenJDK site, the results can be less than useful -- e.g. use Google to search for `Inet4Address site:http://hg.openjdk.java.net/` So, download a source bundle instead and unpack the archive. On Windows, use the search tool of your choice, even Windows search after an index update. On Linux, Unix, or Mac OS X, enter this on the command line in the root directory of the unpacked files: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 egrep -l Inet4Address` That will return the files containing "Inet4Address."

Comment: If you want to see the lines of code and page through them, use this instead: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 egrep Inet4Address | more` Add the `-c` option to egrep to see lines of "context" before and after the line in a file containing "Inet4Address." For more options and details, run this command: `man egrep`

Answer (score 4):

any self-respecting IDE will do that for you. just open the class and do find usages in intellij idea or references-->workspace in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

import the sources to eclipse after that you can use `Ctrl+Shift+G` to find where is that class used